# Synchronized block on a ConcurrentHashMap : What will be the lock placed on?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I have an application with 16-32 threads and a ConcurrentHashMap with the state in a graph as a key and AtomicInteger as a value.

If I want to lock the values using the synchronized keyword on the ConcurrentHashMap: `synchronized(MyConcurrentHashMap)`

Will it lock the entire ConcurrentHashMap (making it no longer concurrent), only the accessed buckets or the AtomicInteger?
Will there be any difference if I synchronize on the AtomicInteger instead of the ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` does not synchronize on itself anywhere in the code.  So you will only be `synchronized` against other places where _you_ are `synchronized` on the same instance.

Comment: @user2478398 I don't have it at other places. I only use it at one place inside code run in an ExecutorService and have multiple threads running the same code. So what will be exactly locked? Will there be any difference if I synchronize on the AtomicInteger instead of the ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: If you're using `ConcurrentHashMap` and `AtomicInteger`, the entire idea of these classes is to handle asynchronous access _without_ synchronisation.  At a guess, you really shouldn't be synchronising anything here...
But to answer the question, the access to the block of code within the `synchronized` section will be locked to only one entrant for each thread which arrives at it using the same instance of the `Map`.  And without seeing code on how you're using an `AtomicInteger` I can't say if it would be the same.